# Add timestamp to finished task

Tags: org-mode

Upon getting a task done from org mode

```
* TODO A task
```

Invoke C-c C-t, change it's state to

- DONE a task

How could add a active timestamp to the finished task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(setq org-log-done t)
```

It will look like this:

```
* DONE A task
  CLOSED: [2019-08-28 Wed 17:59]
```

As it says in the documentation you can invoke with `describe-variable`:

> Information to record when a task moves to the DONE state.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> - `nil`     Don’t add anything, just change the keyword
> - `time`    Add a time stamp to the task
> - `note`    Prompt for a note and add it with template ‘org-log-note-headings’
>
> This option can also be set with on a per-file-basis with
>
> ```
> #+STARTUP: nologdone
> #+STARTUP: logdone
> #+STARTUP: lognotedone
> ```
>
> You can have local logging settings for a subtree by setting the LOGGING
>   property to one or more of these keywords.

Comment: Can you elaborate with something like documentation for the variable you're customizing with your code?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: I've modified my answer even though I think that every Emacs user would be able to find the documentation faster than it took me to paste it here.

Comment: Answers should be self contained, so if there's any relevant documentation, it should be quoted in the answer.